# Making PyCharm search for a file at project's paths

Tags: python, pycharm

Correct me if I'm wrong but PyCharm used to auto-complete the path for files located in the project's tree. For example when trying to open a file placed in your projects directory, the first character typed at *open* function's first argument would lead to the specified file.

Nowadays PyCharm seems to have another path as the default one for file searching. Is there a way to reconfigure PyCharm so I won't need to look up the absolute path of a file?

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot with an example and your project structure (`Project` tool window on the left side)

Answer (score 0):

There are Project settings and there are IDE settings for Pycharm

Project settings are stored with each specific project as a set of `.xml` files under the `.idea` folder. If you specify the template project settings, these settings will be automatically used for each newly created project.

IDE settings are stored in the dedicated directories under PyCharm home directory. The PyCharm directory name is composed of the product name and version.

All of these directories default to standards for Windows Mac and Linux. It sounds like you have some settings in the .idea folder that should be changed.  Have a look and keep a safe copy of the files (or a source code controlled version) before you mess with them.